# The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' .How to fix this 'screen shot below'

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I downloaded new visual studio 2019  , download blazor extention and dotnet 3.0 core and follow some steps to start using blazor , what i  missed here?

[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCvyi.png)

[what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw9Ox.png)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: help me please..

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061361/the-type-of-namespace-mvc-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft-aspnet

Comment: What is missing is the badge [Preview] in the top right menu bar. Blazor doesn't work (well) on the regular VS2019 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 official release doesn't yet have complete support for Blazor. (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10421)

[Download the latest preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) and [re-follow the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) on how to get started.